# Unchecked Checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a web form that has a check box in it. The form is created dynamically so there could be multiple checkboxes on this form. I need to know whether it is checked or not. The problem is an unchecked checkbox POSTs nothing at all.

I know this has been asked before but the solution is always to provide a hidden field with a the value. The problem I have is I need to know whether it was checked out not, not necessarily the value. Is there a way to make this happen? I was thinking I would need to use some javascript but not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a hidden input with the same name but the value `"off"`. Make sure it is located before the checkbox in the document. Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="something" value="off" />
<input type="checkbox" name="something" />
```

This will submit the following:

```
// if the box is unchecked:
something=off
// if the box is checked:
something=off&something=on
```

Since duplicate names results in overwriting the previous value (except in the case of arrays), you will always get `$_POST['something']` that is either `"on"` (checked) or `"off"` (unchecked).

Comment: You must provide a value for checkboxes. Defaulting on `on` is an error recovery strategy browsers have implemented, authors should not depend on that.

Comment: @Quentin As far as I've seen the browser will always submit the string `"on"` regardless of the `value` attribute of the checkbox...

Comment: — Yes? Error recovery strategies are not a license to not care about the error.

Comment: I think this will work my concern is that since my inputs are an array because of the dynamic nature in which they are created will this instead append the hidden value instead of overwriting it with the checked value.

I will try and and come back and approve answer if it works

Comment: This works when not using arrays. So I accepted the answer because this will help most people I believe. The solution for me was just to create a Radio and deal with it that way. I originally didn't want to go this route because I am dealing with people that don't know computers and I didn't want to muddy up the screen. Oh well! Thansk for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to see if the `$_POST` index is set

```
if (isset($_POST['myCheckBox'])) { ... }
```

Comment: No. As the question says, if a field isn't checked it isn't submitted.

Comment: @quentin **EXACTLY**. If it's not submitted the index won't be set. The **FORM** submits, not the **INPUT**. Please remove your -1.

Comment: — The question also says that the checkboxes that are there aren't known in advance. So the objective is to find out which checkboxes exist then which of them were checked.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not going to write his code for him - he can figure out a naming scheme that allows him to dynamically check which checkboxes are there.

Comment: @Matt There is no such scheme. Even something as simple as consecutive numbers fails due to not knowing if `X` exists and is unchecked, or if the numbers stopped at `X-1`.

Comment: @kolink perhaps a hidden input containing the total number of checkboxes that were printed?

Comment: Matt as Quentin says this does nothing. If I have 4 check boxes and 1, 2, and 4 are checked but 3 isn't I get an array that shows 0 => 'on', 1 => 'on, 2 => 'on'. Checking if my data posts doesn't really help.